# Combining arrays from multiple threads using std::thread

Tags: c++11, stdthread

I am writing a Monte Carlo program in C++ and am using std::thread to divide the number of histories to be tracked between the threads.  However, this is my first attempt at multithreading and I have encountered a problem that this simplified code should hopefully let me demonstrate in the hopes that I can get some advice from the readers of this site.  In this simplified problem, I am calling the function Summation that produces a 1X5 dimensional array of random numbers with 2 threads. When the threads return their values (not really returned since it is a global variable), the main program then has two five dimensional arrays, with each array corresponding to a different thread.  I would like to combine the two arrays into a single array, with the elements in the final array, corresponding to the sum of the same elements in the two arrays that were produced by different threads.  Unfortunately the arrays from each thread have the same name, so I can not simply add the two different arrays together.  What methods are recommended to combine the two 1X5 dimensional arrays into a single summation array with elements corresponding to the sum of the identical elements from each thread?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <cassert>
#include "boost/multi_array.hpp"

std::vector<float> Array;
std::mutex Array_mutex;

void Summation(int sample_size)
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(Array_mutex);
    for(int i = 0; i < sample_size; i++)
    {
        Array.push_back(rand() % 10 + 1);
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    int sample_size = 10;
    int Num_Threads = 2;
    int number_count = sample_size/Num_Threads;
    srand(time(NULL));
    std::vector<std::thread> Threads;
    for(int i = 0; i < Num_Threads; i++)
    {
        Threads.push_back(std::thread(Summation,number_count));
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < Num_Threads; i++)
    {
        Threads[i].join();
    }

    // - I would like to combine the arrays produced from each thread into a
    //   single array, where each element in the final array is the sum of
    //   the identical element in the array from each thread

    // i.e. Element 1(final) = Element 1(thread 1) + Element 1(thread2)
    //      Element 2(final) = Element 2(thread 1) + Element 2(thread2)
    //      Element 3(final) = Element 3(thread 1) + Element 3(thread2)

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Two things: Let each of the tread do a little bit of the calculations, so one thread does entries 1 to 10, another 11 to 20, and so on. If the vector is created with a fixed size (or if you're using `std::array`) then you don't need a lock. The other thing is, initialize the random number generator *once* only.

Comment: Also, you don't *have* multiple arrays (or vectors) to "combine" in your code, all threads will write to the same array. In fact, disregard the first part of my previous comment, as your problem is another one, and that is that you don't have multiple vectors, only one.

Comment: O.K., this is good information that changes my understanding of the output.  If it is the same array, then that means the data from one thread is overwriting the data produced by the second thread, which is why I get two array when I print them with a std::cout command, but in reality it is the same array/memory slot printed twice with overwritten data.  If this is true, then how can I get each thread to make a separate array that can be combined in another thread or main program?

Comment: One of the many reasons that `std::rand` is terrible is its lack of thread-safety. You should use the [random number generation facilities in `<random>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) instead.

Comment: I only used std::rand for this example, normally I used a LANL RNG that was developed for the MCNP code, but i did not want to confuse anyone with the implementation of it on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want one vector per thread, you actually need to have *one vector per thread*. Like a vector of vectors.

For a simple and naive solution, something like

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <random>
#include <thread>

void generate(const size_t size, std::array<float>& values)
{
    // Pseudo-random number generation stuff
    std::random_device rd;
    std::default_random_engine e1(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<float> uniform_dist(1, 10);

    // Generate some values and add the array
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        values[i] = uniform_dist(el);
}

int main()
{
    constexpr size_t number_values  = 10;
    constexpr size_t number_threads = 2;

    // An array of arrays, one sub-array per thread
    std::array<std::array<float, number_values>, number_threads>
        values;

    // An array of threads
    std::array<std::thread, number_threads> threads;

    // Create threads
    for (size_t i = 0; i < number_threads; ++i)
        threads[i] = std::thread(generate, number_values, std::ref(values[i]));

    // Wait for threads to finish
    for (size_t i = 0; i < number_threads; ++i)
        threads[i].join();

    // Now "combine" the values into a single array
    std::array<float, number_values> totals;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < number_values; ++i)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < number_threads; ++j)
            totals[i] += values[j][i];
    }

    // Print the values
    for (const size_t i; i < number_values; ++i)
        std::cout << "Value #" << (i + 1) << " = " << totals[i] << '\n';
}
```

Note that the code is untested, and not even compiled, but should work *in theory*. :)

Comment: Thank you for the example, A picture paints a thousand words! ;-)

Comment: With exception of a few issues the code works very well.  The only issue was the fact that the values array has to be allocated in the function call.  Unfortunately my problem requires a dynamic array allocation since i never know how many monte carlo detectors will be used in the user defined problems.  I tried everything I could think of with vector and points and nothing worked.  In the end I gave in an just way over allocated the array to ensure the user can define as many detectors as they wish.  Thanks for the help with this example.